# Building Firefox OS 2.2 on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: gcc, ubuntu-14.04, firefox-os

I am trying to build Firefox OS 2.2 on Ubuntu 14.04, but I keep running into an error that reads:

```
configure: error: Only GCC 4.6 or newer supported
*** Fix above errors and then restart with\
               "make -f client.mk build"

> Build failed! <
```

This would normally lead me to suspect I might need GCC 4.6, but I am already using that. I have successfully built 2.0 and 2.1 on this machine in the past, and 1.1-1.4 previously on one of the '13 versions of Ubuntu before that, and I have had `export CC=gcc-4.6` and `export CXX=g++-4.6` in `.profile` practically since I installed 14.04 on this machine.

To see if I could spot anything obvious in the output I `tee`'d it to a file, and it is taking a good 7000 lines of output to reach the point where suddenly it thinks I am using a different `gcc`. If I change `CC` and `CXX` to not specify the version then it complains a lot sooner, so I take that to suggest that it is finding the right version for quite a while before complaining about this?

In any case, I am not finding anything else quite like this, and my experience with building mobile OSes is admittedly limited (only Firefox OS builds) but up until now the instructions have either worked or produced errors I could find someone else posting about already. Hopefully someone else happens to know something about why `gcc-4.6` would give an error about needing version 4.6?

### Edit

Turns out, there is a [Bugzilla Bug Report (1121600)](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1121600) that mentions this. If I get the general sense of what it says, I think there is some kind of configuration thing wrong that is known to be true for some of the models that one can compile Firefox OS for?

I thought I would go ahead and put something about that here, since I ran into that. I wish I had a better sense of what the issue was so I could just fix it for my one device, but in case that is helpful to someone else searching for this who has not come up with the terms that led me there yet, that is apparently what is going on.

Comment: Which device are you trying to build? I'm one of the guys who submitted a patch for it.

Comment: You should consider to use an vagrant environment for compiling, instead of installing tons of dev-tools on your workstation. .

Answer (score 0):

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1121600

try replace:

```
<project name="platform_build" path="build" remote="gp-b2g" revision="501521623cc9a3117799a040e868bddf26b6cbde">
```

with:

```
<project name="platform_build" path="build" remote="gp-b2g" revision="3ce5007ab3562021551a35e2c06d323d1e8ee048">
```

and comment in config.sh (or will override your change)

```
repo_sync() {
rm -rf .repo/manifest* &&
```

to:

```
repo_sync() {
#rm -rf .repo/manifest* &&
```

finally execute the config script again

```
BRANCH=v2.2 ./config.sh <YOUR DEVICE>
```

Comment: btw this is an immediate solution not the final-one....witch device are you trying to config?